# Delete values from the settings application (iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios6

I have a settings bundle for my app with key name Users and type mutlivalue. When I run the app and go to settings application, I am able to select the Users. I want an option to delete the users just like we do in table view. Is this possible?
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Never try to delete any resource from NSBundle in iPhone/iPad/iPod on runtime
This tip is only meant to reduce your effort on developing iPhone/iPad application.

Basically in an app you developed a logic that on run time you need to delete some resource from NSBundle time(which is through coding).As initailly the application is run on simulator by most developers.it will work perfectly with no issue.

But when you  run the same application on device i.e iPhone/iPad it will show a error i,e `NSCocoaErrorDomain = 513.`

What it means is that on runtime in device the bundle has only read permisson not write.
So when designing the applications do not include logic that deletes the resource from NSBundle on run time because it will work perfectly in iPhone/iPad simulator.

Author: [Subrat Kheti](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Never-try-to-delete-any-resource-from-NSBundle-in-iPhoneiPadiPod-on-runtime-1523.php)